# Evaluate a macro only once

Tags: macros

In my LaTeX document I will need often a specific value in a table. So I can define the following macro :

```
\newcommand{\values}{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\mydata\pgfplotsretval}
```

The pgfplotstable manual recommands not to use this command in a loop :

> **Attention**: If possible, avoid using this command inside of loops. It is quite slow.

It would be wise to compute only once the value of `\value` and then use it as often as I want without slowing down the compilation. What is the best way to do this ?

Here is a sample code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
1,15,53
5,74,12
}\mydata
\renewcommand{\value}{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\mydata\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{document}
This is the first values : \values
\end{document}
```

Comment: In principle: yes, but it depends strongly on what kind of "computation" you do. Is the outcome a simple number? A text? A graphical element? A minipage?

Comment: The thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589 might be of interest to you (this comment is unrelated to your question, it is merely about general programming practices in TeX)

Comment: An example would be very useful: as it stands the question is too generic for getting a good answer.

Comment: *DON'T* redefine `\value`! Use any other name, but not the one reserved for a *very* important function of the LaTeX kernel!

Comment: It's corrected now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\mydata
```

the macro `\pgfplotsretval` expands just to the computed value. Thus you just need to define your macro to be the current expansion of `\pgfplotsretval`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
1,15,53
5,74,12
}\mydata
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\mydata

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\myvalue}{\let\myvalue\pgfplotsretval}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the first value: \myvalue
\end{document}
```

---

#### Important warning

Never use `\renewcommand` if you don't know precisely what you're doing. The macro `\value` is a very important function of the LaTeX kernel. Redefining it will break a huge number of internal functions.

Comment: Perfect ! About the \renewcommand, I decided to use it just for this minimal example but I will avoid it in the future.